# How to get the right vpn configurations

Tags: vpn, openvpn

So, I am in a more or less locked network next week where many ports are blocked.
I now that port 443 is not locked (ssh dont work with port 20 but woth 443).
I already tried to setup a OpenVPN server on my own Server that uses port 443 but I cant connect to it. Next thing I tried was a outline vpn Server on another Server but that also doesnt work.

Then I found the vpn Service hide.me and tried there test version and with one click I got an Connection and everything works like it should; nothing is blocked anymore.
So here is my question:
Can I somehow extract Infos from the hide.me client what protocol etc it uses to set my openvpn/outline vpn to the same settings to get it to work?
Or do you guys now another solution how I can get the Infos how to setup my vpn right like that one from hide.me?

(Connection to my Server is possible; ping, ssh over 443 works)

Comment: If ssh wors over 443 so wil OpenVPN. Are you sure you configured TCP and not UDP, and did you run it as root so it can bind to low ports?

Comment: yes, thats what I dont get too. It was tcp 443 with root permissions. For info, I once tried to run [Parsec](https://parsecgaming.com/) with port 443 and this didnt work on this Network too.